# Does a geodesic locally minimize the curvature?

Tags: geometry, curvature, geodesic

Does a geodesic somehow minimize the local curvature? Lets say we have a smooth geodesic $\gamma$ with constant speed on a surface $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and with $\gamma(t)=x$, then every other smooth curve $\eta$ on $S$ with the same speed such that $\eta(t)=x$ has a a curvature which is greater or equal to the one of $\gamma$ at $t$? Does this somehow characterizes the geodesic?

Comment: What curvature are you referring to? The Riemann curvature tensor or the geodesic curvature? Or any of the extrinsic curvatures?

Comment: @ArcticChar, I read a bit the wikipedia article about Riemann curvature and geodesic curvature and I would like to talk about the [geodesic curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_curvature), i.e. the curvature of the curve projected onto the surface's tangent plane. In the wiki link, it is written : geodesics have zero geodesic curvature. Now since I was interested if this property characterizes the geodesic, I am asking for the reverse question : Are curves with zero geodesic curvature geodesics?